# How to Set Email Subject Line and Email Message from JSON in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Could anyone explain to me that how to set email subject line and email message using JSON in Docusign.

Note:(JSON string has to be passed as HTTP request).

Thank you,
Vignesh.B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[emailNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters)** property to set  separate email subject and email body per each individual recipient. The emailNotification property should be set per recipient.

Here is a sample Json for the [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "recipientone@acme.com",
        "name": "recipient one",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the  document Recipient One ",
              "emailBody": "Hello Recipient One,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
         },
        "tabs": {"signHereTabs": [{"documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "100", "yPosition": "100"}]}
      },
      {
        "email": "recipienttwo@acme.com",
        "name": "recipient two",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "emailNotification": {
              "emailSubject": "Please sign the  document Recipient Two ",
              "emailBody": "Hello Recipient Two,\r\n\r\nYour consultant has sent you a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the document.  If you have any questions, please contact your consultant.\r\n\r\nThank you!",
              "supportedLanguage": "en"
         },        
        "tabs": {"signHereTabs": [{"documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "100", "yPosition": "200"}]}
      }
    ]
  },
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "txt",
      "name": "Simple Contract",
      "order": "1"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Sent"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **emailSubject** and **emailBlurb** properties to set the subject and message for all the recipients in the envelope. These properties have to be set at the root level of your json request.

Note: You can override the properties at the envelope level by specifying the **emailNotification** property for each recipient as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723712/1219543)

Here is a sample Json for the [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
 "emailSubject": "Email subject for all recipients",
 "emailBlurb": "Email body for all recipients",
 "status": "Sent",
 "recipients": {
     "signers": [
         {
             "email": "recipientone@acme.com",
             "name": "recipientone",
             "recipientId": "1",
             "routingOrder": "1",
             "tabs": { "signHereTabs": [ { "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "100", "yPosition": "100" } ] }

         },
         {
             "email": "recipienttwo@acme.com",
             "name": "recipient two",
             "recipientId": "2",
             "routingOrder": "1",
             "tabs": { "signHereTabs": [ { "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "100", "yPosition": "200" } ] }
         }
     ]
 },
 "documents": [
     {
         "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP",
         "documentId": "1",
         "fileExtension": "txt",
         "name": "Simple Contract",
         "order": "1"
     }
 ]
}
```