# DocuSign Request error "Envelope definition missing."

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to make 'createAndSendEnvelope' request using DocuSign REST api/v2. My JSON is valid.

I came across the same question and I tried the solution given in there i.e. I made sure all new lines use '\r\n'.

What am I missing here? Here is my request, I get error code, "message": "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Envelope definition missing."

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/envelopes HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"xxxxxx","Password":"xxxxx","IntegratorKey":"xxxxxx"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 90500
Expect: 100-continue


--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data
{
    "status": "sent",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "tabs": {
                "signHeretabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "15",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentid": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Sign Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "initialsTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "45",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "receipientId": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Initials Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "dateSignedTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "65",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "receipientid": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentid": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": "-5",
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Date Signed",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }]
            },
            "routingorder": "1",
            "rolename": "roleNameHere",
            "recipientid": "1",
            "name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "email": "xxxxx@gcpa.com"
        }]
    },
    "emailsubject": "TestDocuSign Call",
    "emailBlurb": "Test Email Blurb",
    "documents": [{
        "name": "Name1",
        "fileExtension": ".pdf",
        "documentId": "1",
        "documentBase64": null
    }]
}
--AAA
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Name1.pdf"; documentid="1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
VGhpcyBpcyBh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your base64 encoded document bytes in the **documentBase64** property

POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/envelopes HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"xxxxxx","Password":"xxxxx","IntegratorKey":"xxxxxx"}

Content-Type: application/json

```
{
 "status": "sent",
 "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
        "tabs": {
                <Removed tabs for brevity>
        },
        "routingorder": "1",
        "rolename": "roleNameHere",
        "recipientid": "1",
        "name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "email": "xxxxx@gcpa.com"
    }]
 },
 "emailsubject": "TestDocuSign Call",
 "emailBlurb": "Test Email Blurb",
 "documents": [{
    "name": "Name1",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",
    "documentId": "1",
    "documentBase64": "VGhpcyBpcyBh"
 }]
}
```

Comment: I tried specifying the document bytes in the **documentBase64** property, but still get same error. I am trying this request from not main stream languages like Java but from SalesForce Apex and I think that should not cause this issue. I wish the error message was a bit more specific.

Comment: Did you change your content type to application/json?

Comment: Yes I did.Below is my request.removed tabs to save space
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data
{
 "status": "sent",
 "recipients": {
  "signers": [{<tabs here>},
   }]
 },
 "emailSubject": "TestDocuSign Call", 
 "emailBlurb": "Test Email Blurb",
 "documents": [{
  "name": "Name1",
  "fileExtension": ".pdf",
  "documentId": "1",
  "documentBase64": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNhbXBsZSBmaWxlIHVwbG9hZCBmb3IgdGVzdGluZy4="
 }]
}
--AAA--

Comment: You should no longer specify the boundary if your content-type is application/json. Remove  ---AAA---

Comment: See here for another example https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726368/1219543

Comment: can you please tell me what should be headers? I have to accomodate multiple documents, so I was setting content header request.setHeader to ( 'Content-type','multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA' ); Also I guess I do not need to specify Content-Disposition:form-data now, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MK2007 set ( 'Content-type','application/json' ); no need to specify Content-Disposition:form-data

Comment: I wish we could chat/email. I tried the above and now I get   "errorCode": "ANCHOR_TAG_PROCESSING_FAILURE",
  "message": "An Error Occurred during anchor tag processing. Invalid document"

Comment: I got the above resolved by putting the correct extension for the document. Thanks alot for all your help. One final question, if I need to use url to oen the docuSign in different tab in SalesForce how do I construct that url? any sample url you can point me to?

Comment: ,can you please point me to example or documentation link for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894120/using-js-function-to-open-docusign-in-new-tab