# Using JS function to open Docusign in new tab

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am attempting to open a new docusign tab in my salesforce application. I understand I need to construct a url for this, but do not know what are the required parameters to be passed. So the url will look something like **/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?**
Where can I see the list of parameters and what is minimum required and what is optional? I have envelope Id and Document Id. I need to open a new tab where it shows the envelope populated with all the fields like signers and documents attached.[I need to open this page with attachments and everything in the envelope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6q0f.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am not using javascript but using apex making a post request to get the embedded signing url.